# not able to create zip file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, download, zip

**Below is the code to generate the zip of multiple files:**

```
<?php 

$file1 = 'D:/xampp/htdocs/pdf/pdffiles/14816393105-annexc-form.pdf';
$file2 = 'D:/xampp/htdocs/pdf/pdffiles/14816393105-resident-form.pdf'

$files = array($file1,$file2);
$zipname = time().'-file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
   $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);

?>
```

**This code does create the zip file but it is corrupted.**

**EDIT:**

**`zip file is created but if i extract it then it is from the D:/ drive. Means zip file contains this:`xampp\htdocs\pd‌​f\pdffiles\file1.pdf**

Comment: 1 - Is the file on your server (before downloading) corrupted too? 2 - Does it work if you add a 2nd param (filename) in `addFile` method?

Comment: Open the file with a text editor and check if there are empty lines at the top. If so, does it normalize in case you remove them? In this situation, check your php files to see where they return empty lines.

Comment: @rap-2-h no it is not corrupted. 2 - Does it work if you add a 2nd param (filename) in addFile method? - means?

Comment: @PathikVejani $zip->addFile($file, 'foo.pdf');

Comment: @rap-2-h `$file`it self file name

Comment: @rap-2-h zip file is created but if i extract it then the path is like this: `\1481641789-file\xampp\htdocs\pdf\pdffiles\file1.pdf`

Comment: Ok so I just added a full answer just below. Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify a filename in `addFile` method. It is not obvious, since there are no noticeable examples around, but you can use `$localname` (second parameter) to define and control file/directory structure inside the zip. Use it if you do not want files to be included with their absolute directory tree.

Here is a working example using `basename`:

```
$file1 = 'D:/xampp/htdocs/pdf/pdffiles/14816393105-annexc-form.pdf';

// ...

$zip->addFile($file1, basename($file1));
```

`basename` returns trailing name component of path, so it will just keep `14816393105-annexc-form.pdf` and add it to your zip.

Comment: yeah.. it is the solution.. and how to download the file?

Comment: @PathikVejani  You can also use `FCPATH . 'pdffiles/14816393105-annexc-form.pdf'` . which is absolute path saves typing in full path.